# netplan route source/destination yaml

Tags: networking, netplan

I have network setup where I have dual nic’s connected directly with fibers to a device which sends data only. This device never listen. The problem is that this device only have one source address, but luckily it can have many destination addresses

The setup looks like this

10.50.1.10———————> ens6f0 10.50.1.129/25

10.50.1.10———————> ens6f1 10.50.1.1/25

Of course no problem with the connection between 10.50.1.10 and 10.50.1.1 on interface ens6f1

How to setup the netplan yaml so interface ens6f0 understands that the packets coming from ip 10.50.1.10 to 10.50.1.129 should be handled by that device.

The Ubuntu version is 18.04 LTS

// Assar W.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, you are declaring a netmask of `/25` on each interface.  But for an address of `10.50.1.129` with a netmask of `/25`, the source address of `10.50.1.10` is not on the same network (valid IP addresses for the /25 are in the range 10.50.1.129-255).

You must either declare your network so that the source address is within the network (so using a /24 or shorter netmask), or you must add a host route for 10.50.1.10 declaring it to be on link.

Given that you say that the IP address only ever sends traffic and does not listen, I think it is appropriate to just use a /24 netmask.

Comment: Thank you for your answer
Actually I have tested to use a/24 net mals, but no success. How actually would the netplan setup be where you setup that 10.50.10 is declared to be a link?

Comment: See the documentation for 'on-link' in the `netplan(5)` manpage and https://netplan.io/reference.  However if setting a /24 doesn't work, I don't expect setting an on-link route to fix it either.